# Elasticsearch mapping document for epoch in seconds

Tags: elasticsearch

As far as I understand, es only supports epoch in ms. My data source is couchbase and the json documents in there have an insertEpoch that is stored in seconds. I have been struggling to make my mapping document do the seconds to ms conversion for me.

Here is my mapping doc:

```
{
    "template" : "cb*",
    "order" : 10,
    "mappings" : {
        "couchbaseCheckpoint" : {
            "_source" : {
                "includes" : ["doc.*"]
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "store_no_index": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "store" : "no",
                            "index" : "no",
                            "include_in_all" : false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "couchbaseDoc" : {
            "_source" : {
                "includes" : ["meta.*","doc.*"]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "meta" : {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "include_in_all" : false
                },
                "doc" : {
                    "type" : "nested",
                    "include_in_all" : false,
                    "transform": {
                        "script": "ctx._source['insertEpoch'] = ctx._source['insertEpoch'] * 1000",
                        "params": {},
                        "lang": "groovy"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The transform isn't happening.

New mapping document:

```
{
    "template" : "wheepl",
    "order" : 10,
    "mappings" : {
        "couchbaseCheckpoint" : {
            "_source" : {
                "includes" : ["doc.*"]
            },
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "store_no_index": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "store" : "no",
                            "index" : "no",
                            "include_in_all" : false
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "couchbaseDoc" : {
            "_timestamp" : {
                "enabled" : true,
                "store" : true
            },
            "properties" : {
                "meta" : {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "include_in_all" : false
                },
                "doc" : {
                    "type" : "object",
                    "include_in_all" : false,
                    "updateEpoch" : {
                        "type" : "date",
                        "format" : "date_time",
                        "numeric_resolution" : "seconds"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't even see the _timestamp field that I should be seeing!

Here's a Kibana screenie:

[image: kibana screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: What ES version are you using? This should work in 1.6: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10420

Comment: @AndreiStefan 1.4.5.

Comment: I'll upgrade to 1.6. Though, even while looking at the indexed data I still see my 'updateEpoch' in ms and not seconds.

Comment: Then you need 1.6.0 to be able to have something like this: `"timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time",
          "numeric_resolution": "seconds"
        }`

Comment: upgraded to 1.6.0. I removed the code that does the transform and added  your code while modifying "timestamp" to "updateEpoch". Updated my question with my new mapping file. Whats super strange is that I don't even see the _timestamp field - at the very least, this way Kibana can visualize something (else, Kibana is pretty much useless without a timestamp)

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand. What is the real mapping of that index? `GET /whatever_index/_mapping`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81512/discussion-between-wholly-cow-and-andrei-stefan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in 1.6, as per https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10420.
Even if, internally, the date itself will be kept in milliseconds, you can index it as seconds, retrieve it as seconds, meaning just like you indexed it.

I've tried out a simple test, to see this in action:

```
PUT /test_dates
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "time_stamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "date_time",
          "numeric_resolution": "seconds"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test data:

```
POST /test_dates/test/1
{
  "time_stamp": "9231200"
}
```

Retrieving it:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_dates",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "time_stamp": "9231200"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

To prove it works, running this aggregation:

```
GET /test_dates/test/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "time_stamp",
        "interval": "second",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
   "aggregations": {
      "NAME": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key_as_string": "1970-04-17",
               "key": 9231200000,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Also, your template is a bit wrong. It should be:

```
"couchbaseDocument": {
    "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "meta": {
            "type": "object",
            "include_in_all": false
        },
        "doc": {
            "type": "object",
            "include_in_all": false,
            "properties": {
                "updateEpoch": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_time",
                    "numeric_resolution": "seconds"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```